# Interior Derivative and Contraction: Kobayashi and Nomizu.

Tags: differential-geometry

In Kobayashi & Nomizu, the interior derivative of an r-form is defined as $\iota_X \omega = C(X \otimes \omega)$, where $C$ is the contraction associated with the pair $(1,1)$ and $\omega$ is interpreted as a tensor of type $(0,r)$. They then claim that
\begin{equation*}
(\iota_X)(Y_1, \dots, Y_{r-1}) = r \; \omega(X, Y_1, \dots, Y_{r-1})
\end{equation*}
My question is: where does the factor of $r$ come from? This seems to be inconsistent with their previous conventions for forms.

Since they define $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 = \frac{1}{2}(\omega_1 \otimes \omega_2  - \omega_2 \otimes \omega_1)$, we should have
\begin{equation*}
C(X \otimes (\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2))(Y) = \frac{1}{2}( \omega_1(X) \omega_2(Y) - \omega_2(X) \omega_1(Y))
\end{equation*}
whereas, using the determinant convention in K&N, given by
\begin{equation*}
\omega_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \omega_n = \frac{1}{n!} \det(\omega_i(X_j))
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
2 (\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2)(X,Y) = 2 \frac{1}{2} (\omega_1(X) \omega_2(Y) - \omega_2(X) \omega_1(Y))
\end{equation*}
and so the two expressions are not equal. Where does the problem arise?

Comment: I've just come across the same problem. Did you figure out why that was?